# How to await a function in javascript that has a promise inside?

Tags: javascript

When I have the following function:

```
axios
      .get(
        `${config.server}/getUsers.php`,
        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }
      )
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

I can do something after I receive the users with `.then()`.

But what, if I put this request in a function:

```
const getUsers = () => {
   axios
      .get(
        `${config.server}/getUsers.php`,
        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }
      ).then(() => {
          return true;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
          return false;
      });
};
```

How can I do something if `getUsers()` is done and true?

Comment: `return axios.get()` and then `getUsers.then()`.  You have to propogate the promise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: just remove the curlies and the useless `then` and `catch`: `const getUsers = () => axios.get(....)`, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor your code like this:

```
const async getUsers = () => {
  try {
    let users = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `${config.server}/getUsers.php`,
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });
    return {success: true, result: users};
  } catch (error) {
    return {success: false, error};
  }
};
```

If the request was successful you can return `success: true` with `result` data. If the request failed for some reason you can return `success: false` and the `error`.

**NOTE:** When you use `async` syntax, the function will return a `Promise`, so you can do `.then()` when you call `getUsers()` is some other function, or you can also use `async` syntax.

With `.then()` it will look something like:

```
someOtherFunction() => {
  getUsers().then((users)=>{
    res.status(200).json();
  }).catch((error))=>{
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
}
```

With `async` it will look something like:

```
async someOtherFunction() => {
  try {
    let users = await getUsers();
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't await a function. You can only await a promise (or other thenable).

If `getUsers()` **returned** a promise, then you could call it and await its return value:

```
await getUsers();
```

However, it doesn't. So before you can do that you have to change it so it does return a promise.

```
return axios.get...
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

The Axio-Request is a promise, and therefore, it needs to be wrapped and returned to be thenable:

Like this:

```
const getUsers = () => {
  return axios
    .get(`${config.server}/getUsers.php`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    })
    .then(() => {
      return true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      return false;
    });
};
```

which would let you do something like this:

```
getusers().then((returnedReqData)=>{
    console.log(returnedReqData);
})
```

[This is a good resource for learning how to work with promises, and how to make them thenable.](https://javascript.info/promisify)

Comment: The same concept applies to callbacks, which is called Promisification.